# Multiple Images from external WEB URL

Tags: media

My problem is simple though multiple solutions touch upon it but none address it directly. Hence posting this question.

1. Problem: I have multiple servlet urls (hosted at external web server)
   that returns a single image in response stream. My task is to embed
   images from these (precisely 6) URLs in my drupal site. How can I do
   that.
2. Attempts: I tried using Media Module, Embedd Media Module,
   Custom formatters but none worked for me (may be because I'm a
   beginner). If anyone can help me with some sort of link of steps to achieve this.

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: Also: "Embed" is a bit ambigious. Are you trying to include them in a WYSIWYG editor as part of content? (Assuming since you mentioned embedding and text formatters). We use [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) (with CKEditor) + [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) + [IMCE WYSIWYG Bridge](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg). If you have file/image fields as well you can use [Filefield Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) to integrate IMCE with those.

Comment: drupal version 7.4, Images are field of my custom content type i.e. they are not to be embedded in WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved it in a work-around. I am downloading images inside my drupal accessible folders with the fixed names. Updating these images with fixed names using a background script. Applied cache buster techniques so that images with same names are updated.